# Android - Detect differences between original .wav file and filtered .wav file

Tags: java, android, audio, filter, signal-processing

I have an original .wav file of frequency of 18kHz and 19kHz on the left and right channel.

I have another filtered .wav file that is filtering 18kHz - 20kHz using IIR Filter with bandpass filter.

How do I detect the differences between the two? As in, how do I check that the the audio being implemented with the filter is being filtered successfully?

I am using the library that I found https://github.com/ddf/Minim/blob/master/src/ddf/minim/effects/BandPass.java https://github.com/DASAR/Minim-Android/blob/master/src/ddf/minim/effects/IIRFilter.java

The following is the code relevant to the filtering.

```
float[][] deinterleaveData(float[] samples, int numChannels) {
    // assert(samples.length() % numChannels == 0);
    int numFrames = samples.length / numChannels;

    float[][] result = new float[numChannels][];
    for (int ch = 0; ch < numChannels; ch++) {
        result[ch] = new float[numFrames];
        for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
            result[ch][i] = samples[numChannels * i + ch];
        }
    }
    return result;
}


float[] interleaveData(float[][] data) {
      int numChannels = data.length;
      int numFrames   = data[0].length;

      float[] result = new float[numFrames*numChannels];
      for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
        for (int ch = 0; ch < numChannels; ch++) {
          result[numChannels * i + ch] = data[ch][i];
        }
      }
      return result;
    }

/**
  * Convert byte[] raw audio to 16 bit int format.
  * @param rawdata
  */
private int[] byteToShort(byte[] rawdata) {
  int[] converted = new int[rawdata.length / 2];

  for (int i = 0; i < converted.length; i++) {
    // Wave file data are stored in little-endian order
    int lo = rawdata[2*i];
    int hi = rawdata[2*i+1];
    converted[i] = ((hi&0xFF)<<8) | (lo&0xFF);
  }
  return converted;
}

private float[] byteToFloat(byte[] audio) {
  return shortToFloat(byteToShort(audio));
}

/**
* Convert int[] audio to 32 bit float format.
* From [-32768,32768] to [-1,1] 
* @param audio
*/
private float[] shortToFloat(int[] audio) {
    float[] converted = new float[audio.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < converted.length; i++) {
        // [-32768,32768] -> [-1,1]
        converted[i] = audio[i] / 32768f; /* default range for Android PCM audio buffers) */
    }

    return converted;
}

private void writeAudioDataToFile() throws IOException {
    int read = 0;
    byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    String filename = getTempFilename();
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    FileOutputStream rs = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        rs = new FileOutputStream(getFilename().split(".wav")[0] + ".txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (null != os) {

        BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(19000,2000,44100);
        while (isRecording) {

            // decode and deinterleave stereo 16-bit per sample data
              float[][] signals = deinterleaveData(byteToFloat(data), 2);

              // filter data samples, updating the buffers with the filtered samples.
              bandpass.process(signals[0], signals[1]);

              // recombine signals for playback
              audioTrack.write(interleaveData(signals), 0, count, WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
             // audioTrack.write(data, 0, count);   

                 read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                try {
                    os.write(data);
                    rs.write(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            os.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Full code is here if necessary: http://pastebin.com/23aS2A2w

Do I find the peaks and valleys of the original .wav file and the filtered .wav file to detect the difference? If not, how would I detect?

Thanks for all responses and help. Appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of techniques you could use for measuring the frequency response of a filter.

The first would be to run the filter with pure sine waves at various frequencies and then measure the amplitude of the output. For example, generate a tone at 1kHz with a peak amplitude of 1.0 and run the filter. Then look at the output. If the output is half the amplitude then you can say the filter has 6dB of attenuation at 1kHz. If you do this for enough frequencies you can make a plot of the frequency response with frequency on the x axis and output level on the y axis. This is a pretty crude approach though and requires a lot of points to get fine detail. Also, after changing frequencies you would need to skip some of the output to avoid looking at transients.

Another approach is to measure the impulse response of the filter. You do this by inputing a signal which has a single 1.0 followed by the rest zeros. Taking an FFT of the impulse response will give you the frequency response. You need to be careful though to supply enough samples to the filter to allow the impulse to die out though. You can figure this out by looking at the output samples and determining when the samples decay down to zero.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do I have to use MATLAB to do the above? OR is add the code to my existing android application? Totally new in this dsp shit. :/

Comment: You can just add code to your existing application. You'll need to find a library for performing an FFT though.

Comment: Noted. So I find a FFT library to detect for the differences?

Comment: Yes if you want to use the impulse response method. If you don't have access to FFT then use the other method.